# Attempt to retrieve nested key array value given unkown amount of supplied keys into PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I would like to supply a function with an array of keys (unknown quantity) and a value to then set the corresponding nested array value (using those keys and value). I know how to do this for retrieval, just not for assigning. For retrieval, I do:

```php
function test($keys, $value){
    $arr = ["key1" => ["key2" => true], "key3" => true];

    $nestedArrayValue = $arr;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $nestedArrayValue = $arr[$key];
    }

    return $nestedArrayValue;
}
```

But when assigning a value, that `$nestedArrayValue` is a copy, so it won't actually change the `$arr`. Likewise, if I were to pass by reference where `$nestedArrayValue = &$arr`, the foreach would override the entire `$arr` each time. For example:

```php
function test($keys, $value){
    $arr = ["key1" => ["key2" => true], "key3" => true];

    $nestedArrayValue = &$arr;
    foreach($keys as $key){
        $nestedArrayValue = $arr[$key];
    }

    $nestedArrayValue = $value;

    var_dump($arr);
}

test(["key1", "key2"], "test value");
//OUTPUT:
string(10) "test value"
```

The entire `$arr` gets overridden (which it should). My question is: how do I assign directly to `$arr` given an unknown amount of keys (as an array)? Is it possible?

**UPDATE**:

Here's a pseudo code example of what I am trying to do:

```php
// If this is supplied into function:
["key1","key2"]

// Then this is attempted to be returned:
$arr["key1"]["key2"];
```

I figured out how to do ^ that, but what I can't seem to figure out how to do this:

```php
// If this is supplied for keys:
["key1","key2"] 

// And if this is supplied as value:
"test value"

// Then it should attempt to set:
$arr["key1"]["key2"] = "test value"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: In the first example, you are overriding `$nestedArrayValue` for every iteration using `$nestedArrayValue = $arr[$key]` (assuming the key exists in the `$arr` or else you get `Undefined array key`) So you will always return the last matched keys when having multiple matches. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: In the first example, that is exactly what I want: it returns the nested key value given an array of keys. I'll add a more clear pseudo code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `$nestedArrayValue` reference to the array and in the loop you actually replace the entire array with the value `$arr[$key]`. It was necessary to change the reference to the next key:

```
$nestedArrayValue = &$arr;
foreach($keys as $key){
    // $nestedArrayValue = $arr[$key];
    $nestedArrayValue = &$nestedArrayValue[$key];
}

$nestedArrayValue = $value;
```

And it would also be good to check the key for existence:

```
$nestedArrayValue = &$arr;
$found = true;
foreach($keys as $key){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $nestedArrayValue)) {
        $nestedArrayValue = &$nestedArrayValue[$key];
    } else {
        $found = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    $nestedArrayValue = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect.